# Delete smallest node in a linkedlist

Tags: data-structures, visual-c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have an assignment to delete the smallest node in a linked list. I wrote the function `minelement` for this, but it doesn't delete the smallest node. It just deletes all nodes... why does that happen?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class linkedlist {

private:
    struct node {
        int item;
        node* next;
    };
    node* first;
    node* last;
    int count;

public:
    linkedlist()
    {
        first = last = NULL;
        count = 0;
    }

    bool isempty()
    {
        return (first == NULL);
    }

    void insertnode(int value) {
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->item = value;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            first = last = newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode->next = first;
            first = newNode;
        }
        count++;
    }

    void insertfromLast(int value)
    {
        node* newNODE = new node;
        newNODE->item = value;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            first = last = newNODE;
            newNODE->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = newNODE;
            newNODE->next = NULL;
            last = newNODE;
        }
    }

    void removefirst()
    {
        node* curr = first;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            cout << "empty list cannot be deleted" << endl;

        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            delete first;
            last = first = NULL;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            first = first->next;
            delete curr;
            count--;
        }       
    }

    void removelast()
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            cout << "empty list cannot be deleted" << endl;
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            delete first;
            last = first = NULL;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            node* curr = first->next;
            node* prev = first;
            while (curr != last)
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            delete curr;
            prev->next = NULL;
            last = prev;
            count--;
        }
    }

    void position(int pos)
    {
        node* curr = first;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            cout << "Element's positon cannot be found" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pos > count||pos<0)
            {
                cout << "Out of range so we can't return info of kth element" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
                {
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                cout << curr->item;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    void remove_existed_element(int element)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            cout << "Empty list cannot be deleted" << endl;
        }
        node* curr = first->next;
        node* prev = first;
        if (first->item == element)
        {
            curr = first;
            first = first->next;
            delete curr;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            while (curr != NULL)
            {
                if (curr->item == element)
                {
                    break;
                }
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;

            }
            if (curr == NULL)
            {
                cout << "Element cannot be found to delete" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = curr->next;
                delete curr;
                count--;
            }
        }
    }

    void maxelement()
    {
        int max = first->item;
        node* curr = first->next;
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            if (curr->item > max)   
            {
                max = curr->item;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout << "MAX ELEMENT IS " << max << endl;
        count++;
    }

    void minelement()
    {
        int min = first->item;
        node* curr = first->next;
        node* prev = first;
        if (isempty())
        {
            cout << "Empty linked list cannot be deleted" << endl;      
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            delete first;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            while (curr != NULL)
            {
                if (min > curr->item)
                {
                    min = curr->item;
                }
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            while (curr->item != min) //10 6 5 2//
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr=curr->next;
            }
            prev->next = curr->next;// prev->next=NULL;
            delete (curr);
            count--;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        node* curr = first;
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            cout << curr->item << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    linkedlist l;
    l.insertnode(2);
    l.insertnode(5);
    l.insertnode(6);
    l.insertnode(10);
    l.minelement();
    l.print();
}
```

Comment: Please add code here not on some ephemeral source

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- `curr` is dereferenced when it is *certain* that it is `NULL`:

  ```
  while (curr != NULL)
  {
      if (min > curr->item)
      {
          min = curr->item;
      }
      curr = curr->next;
  }
  while (curr->item != min) // <-- curr will be NULL!!!
  ```
- the function starts with dereferencing `first`, which is not safe: when the list is empty this will be an invalid reference. So the first thing to do is to check whether the list is empty.
- When `count == 1`, the `first` member is not set to `NULL`, ...etc. But since you already have that logic elsewhere, just call `removefirst()`

It is a pity that you have 2 loops: one to find what is the minimum value, and another to find the node that precedes that minimum value. You should do both in one loop.

Here is the updated function:

```
    void minelement()
    {
        if (isempty()) // Check this first!
        {
            cout << "Empty linked list cannot be deleted" << endl;      
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            removefirst(); // Use your method
        }
        else
        {
            // Only access first members when it is safe:
            int min = first->item;
            node* beforemin = NULL;
            node* curr = first->next;
            node* prev = first;
            while (curr != NULL)
            {
                if (min > curr->item)
                {
                    min = curr->item;
                    // Remember where you found it
                    beforemin = prev;
                }
                prev = curr; // keep updated
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            if (beforemin == NULL) {
                removefirst();
            } else if (beforemin->next == NULL) {
                removelast();
            } else {
                curr = beforemin->next;
                beforemin->next = curr->next;
                delete (curr);
                count--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Unrelated to your question, but you should obviously also update the `maxelement` function. The `position` function has some issues too, like:

- `count++;` should not occur there.
- `pos > count` should really be `pos >= count`, because you seem to use position 0 for the head node, and so the last node has position `count-1`.

Finally, try to avoid code duplication. There are too many places where you `delete` and update `count`. Try to centralise such common code in a method and call it where needed.